# If a crime is committed against a poor person , are judges likelier to either interpret the law in a way that favours poor people or punish harshly?

Tags: india

Would there be any problems with a judge or a court doing this ? and is there any legal arguments against something like this at a trial ?

Comment: Judges have at some point probably treated the same circumstances in exactly opposite ways.

Comment: what do you mean

Answer (score 2):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

Courts have recognized that it is an aggravating factor when a person's crime has affected a vulnerable population including people whose vulnerability stems from economic disadvantage or dependence.

The *Criminal Code* *requires* judges to consider such circumstance. It says the sentencing judge must consider (s. 718.2(a)(1)(iii.1)):

> evidence that the offence had a significant impact on the victim, considering their age and other personal circumstances, including their health **and financial situation**

Comment: what are the usual arguments used against this aggravating factor in a trial ? other than "it didn't have a significant effect considering those factors"

Comment: If I punch a rich person or a poor person, it hurts them the same. If I break their tooth with the punch, the rich person goes to the dentist, the poor person can't, so it hurts them more. If I steal $100 from a rich person or a poor person, the poor person may not have money to buy food, so it hurts them a lot more.